# How to make MapView to navigate smoothly in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

im rendering a `MapView`to the screen and all of my functionallity is working fine , the only problem is when i use `Region` instead of `initialRegion` it will move very bad ( like playing a game on 10 fps ! )
how can i fix the problem ?

this is a video from my issue :
https://freeimage.host/i/r0Q9Tb

```
... 
export const MapsScreen = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, clearError, sendRequest } = useHttpClient();
  const [userPlaceError, setUserPlaceError] = useState();
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 35.6997,
    longitude: 51.3381,
    latitudeDelta: 0.02,
    longitudeDelta: 0.02,
  });

  const regionChangeHandler = async (e) => {
    setRegion(e);
    const { latitude, longitude } = e;
    const address = await getAddress(sendRequest, latitude, longitude);
    setAdrress(address);
  };

  return (
    <MapContainer>
      <Map
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        region={region}
        onRegionChange={regionChangeHandler}
        showsUserLocation={true}
      >
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: region.latitude,
            longitude: region.longitude,
          }}
        />
      </Map>
      ...
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onRegionChangeComplete instead of onRegionChange and try adding `tracksViewChanges={false}` into the Marker

onRegionChange will be triggered multiple times and onRegionChangeComplete only once at end.

Comment: its working good thanks , but how can i animate the movement ? for example when i change the region state , movement to the new region somehow be animated and not like jump.

Comment: If you do not want drag and drop for marker then i would suggest just use custom marker as overlay out side the <Map /> that would solve your issue and it will be keep center even if you move map.

Comment: Also use initialRegion instead of the region in the map props as you do not need to update region of map as user himself moving map and you are getting new region in the event handler.